# PHP DOMDocument() getElementsByTagName not working on some URLs

Tags: php, html, dom

First of all, I'm kinda new to PHP DOM elements...

Basically, I'm taking the URL a user entered and output just the video element, like so:

```
    $vidurl = $_REQUEST['url'];

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($vidurl);
    $video = $dom->getElementsByTagName('video')->item(0);

    echo $dom->saveHTML($video);
```

I tried this on a HTML file and it worked perfectly fine:

```
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

But if I enter a URL from YouTube, for example, it shows the whole HTML of the page (picture included),

[image: instead of just displaying a video...]

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks a lot in advance!

Domi

Comment: what is a value of $item ?

Comment: Youtube might require JS, some pages populate the DOM after the initial load.

Comment: @splash58 its 0

Comment: @user3783243 I was thinking that might be the case, I wonder what I could do then...

Comment: Not sure, I've never needed to crawl a js dependent page. I've seen comments in the past suggesting phantomjs.